# Form clear button function doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which has submit button and clear button.  Initially Clear button works fine with no issues but after I submit the form and if no results are found form stays filled and clear button doesn't work. Even if I refresh the page form stays filled. But before submitting if I enter anything and press clear everything works fine. Im not getting any error in the console. very confusing. HELP!

Jquery:

```
function resetHandler(){
$('#type').find('option[value=ALL]').attr("selected",true);
$('#forecastIsc').find('option[value=ALL]').attr("selected",true);
$('#labelNbr').val("");
$('#senderSel').find('option[value=equal]').attr("selected",true);
$('#sender').val("");
$('#recipientSel').find('option[value=equal]').attr("selected",true);
$('#recipient').val("");
$('#divIscCode').hide();
$('#loadDates').hide();
$('#error').hide();
}
```

Form:

```
<td width="5%"><input type="reset" id="reset" value="Clear"/><br>
```

Controller:

```
if(hasError){
        model.addObject("hasError", true);
        model.addObject("errorMessage", errorMessage);
formbean = (SelectionParams)request.getSession().getAttribute("sessionBean");
        //test
        System.err.println("here for testing from viewAnalysisSelection");
        System.err.println("Type is: " + formbean.getType());
        System.err.println("IscCode is: " + formbean.getForecastIsc());
        System.err.println("ActualIscCode is: " + formbean.getActualIsc());
        System.err.println("labelNbr is: " + formbean.getLabelNbr());
        System.err.println("senderOp is: " + formbean.getSenderOp());       
    System.err.println("senderLastName is: " + formbean.getSenderLastName());
        System.err.println("receiverOp is: " + formbean.getReceiverOp());
System.err.println("receiverLastName is: " + formbean.getReceiverLastName());
        model.addObject("parcel", formbean);
        model.addObject("defaultType", formbean.getType());
    }

    model.addObject("noBackTag", true);
```

Comment: where's the rest of your form?

Comment: I think the problem is in controller on 4th line (sessionBean) but I need that there because client wants to see what they have entered wrong in case error occurs but Why the clear button or page refresh doesnt clear the form doesn't work? is there any way to override this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the type to a button instead of reset worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `id` if you input type `reset` change it to some thing else like myreset then it will work. I do not know exactly why we can not have id reset but I had gone through it.

*Html*

```
<td width="5%"><input type="reset" id="myreset" value="Clear"/><br>
```

*Javascript*

```
$('#myreset').click(function(){
  $('form')[0].reset();
});
```

Comment: Changing the id didn't work but changing the type to a button did work! Thanks anyways